# Alternative Data Instead of Flash

Tags: seo, swfobject

I have a Flash file which displays a PDF file as a magazine, because the magazine is in Hebrew Google doesn't read it good.

Is there any why to display raw Text instead of the Flash for the search engine crawlers?
I heard you can do that using SWFObject, is that correct? and if so, how?

I need it to be SEO friendly...

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

SWFObject is still flash, so you don't really change the situation by using that.

Comment: I heard that i can make SWFObject display alternative content to the crawlers in pure HTML...

Answer (score 0):

recreate the pdf file in html; replace the .html file for your .pdf file. although there are extremely better ways to do this, if you're simply loading content via Ajax.